# R: replacing values in string all at once

Tags: regex, r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    USequence
# 1 GATCAGATC
# 2 ATCAGAC
```

I'm trying to create a function that would replace all the G's with C's, A's with T's, C's with G's, and T's with A's:

```
    USequence
# 1 CTAGTCTAG
# 2 TAGTCTG
```

This is what I have right now, the function accepts k, a data frame with a column named USequence.

```
conjugator <- function(k) {
  k$USequence <- str_replace_all(k$USequence,"A","T")
  k$USequence <- str_replace_all(k$USequence,"T","A")
  k$USequence <- str_replace_all(k$USequence,"G","C")
  k$USequence <- str_replace_all(k$USequence,"C","G")
}
```

However the obvious problem would be that this is doesn't replace the characters at once, but rather in steps which would not return the desired result. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a variant of the infamous interview question: "Swap A and B without creating a temp variable"  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `chartr`

```
df1$USequence <- chartr('GATC', 'CTAG', df1$USequence)
df1$USequence 
#[1] "CTAGTCTAG" "TAGTCTG"
```

Or

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn('[GATC]', list(G='C', A='T', T='A', C='G'), df1$USequence)
#[1] "CTAGTCTAG" "TAGTCTG"
```